# How to apply width, min-width and max-width at the same time

Tags: css, width

I have a div, and I am given 3 values for the width of the div. The normal width of the div is 120px, the min width of the div is 90px, and the max width of the div is 150px. I guess I am asked to apply these values based on the width of the screen. I would like to know how to write css for this?

I have tried below code, but it seems my div is always 120px.

```
  .myDiv {
      width: 120px;
      max-width: 150px;
      min-width: 90px;
  }
```

Should I use media query?

Answer (score 0):

`Max-width` and `min-width` as `px` will only have an impact if your `width` is used with percents `%`

(or other window based width like `vw`).

In your case I think indeed the best thing to do is use media queries.

Comment: How to write the media queries in my case?

Comment: @dan sorry for the late answer, you should check this https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/ Also, If i have to do a quick example, as much as i can do is this : 

`@media screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
    // every device with screen width <= 1024px
}
@media screen and (min-width : 1025px) {
    // every screen > 1024px`
}`